# Is it possible to create infinite coins in Monero since Monero is completely anonymous now?

Tags: network

Is it possible to create infinite coins in Monero as it is completely anonymous now? and if such anomaly is created is it possible to find that out in the network?.

Comment: coinbase transactions are still transparent and the supply can be verified by summing all the coinbase transactions from block 0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The coinbase transactions are not anonymised (as they don't need to be), so no, situations like what you describe won't happen. The coinbase transactions will ensure the integrity of the coin supply can be verified.